# Can I change drop out rate when use the call method in tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Here is how I define the MultiRNNCell:

```
    n_lstm_cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hs),
                                                  output_keep_prob=1-dropout_ph,
                                                  variational_recurrent=True,
                                                  dtype=tf.float32) for hs in n_layer_sizes]
    n_multi_rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(n_lstm_cells)
    self.n_multi_rnn_cell = n_multi_rnn_cell
```

the `dropout_ph` is a plcaeholder.
And when I use the `call` method in MultiRNNCell can I change the dropout rate?
Here is an example how I use the call method when I predicting:

```
note_output, new_state = self.n_multi_rnn_cell.call(inputs=indata,state=hidden)
```

The reason why I did this instead of just use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` is that, in predicting, I need the output of each step and then feed this output to another RNN structure to get the final output as input of the next step of `self.n_multi_rnn_cell`. In the precess, it also includes some other operations defined by myself. I use  `tf.scan()`  to do the looping.
Is there a method could treat the dropout rate as one of the inputs of the `call` method?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating another MutilRNNCell with shared(reuse) weights in certain `tf.variable_scope`. And when use the call method, we need to specific the `tf.variable_scope` to `’[YOUR SCOPE]/rnn/mutil_rnn_cell’`.